# How to create Blogger TITLE TAG like on lyrics sites?

Tags: html, header, blogger

I saw on many lyrics sites, they used title tag like this

```
<head>
<title><ARTIST> - <SONGTITLE> Lyrics</title>
</head>
```

Is there any way to create title tag like that on Blogger?
I tried to put these codes but no one of its work!

```
<title><data:label.name/> - <data:blog.pageName/> Lyrics</title>

<title><data:blog.searchLabel/> - <data:blog.pageName/> Lyrics</title>

<title><data:blog.pageTitle/> - <data:blog.pageName/> Lyrics</title>
```

Comment: Are you searching to add HTML meta tags to Blogger ?

Comment: I also put meta tag below title tag. I already did it. And i didn't have a problem with it. I just want display Artist name on Browser Tab, in this case i use Label for Artist names.
I also put label in <h1 class> for my post title
  <span><b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'><span itemprop='title'><data:label.name/> - <data:post.title/> Lyrics</span><b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'> &#187; </b:if></b:loop></span>

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<title><data:blog.pageName/></title>
```

instead of

```
<title><data:blog.title/></title>
```

Source : http://www.bloggerbuster.com/2008/05/change-title-tags-for-your-blog.html